# how to destroy static objects? - issue when testing a static field

Tags: java, testing, junit, static

I would like to test this class and don't want to set id public or allow it to set it from outside.

```
public class A {
    private int id;
    private static int prevId = 0;

    private static nextId(){
        prevId++;
    }

    public A(){
        id = nextId()
    }

    public int getId(){
       return id;
    }

    ...
}
```

if I test it and generate object of A in set up:

```
A foo;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    foo = new A();
}

@Test
public void test1(){
   assertEquals(1, foo.getId());
}

@Test
public void test2(){
    assertEquals(1, foo.getId());
}
```

the test fails because setUp is called twice and therefore
the static field *id* is 2

> assert fail not equals
>   expected 1
>   actual 2

As said above I don't want to have id with public access modifier,
otherwise I could set it to 0 by my own.

Is there a way to destroy the a static object in 
the tear down method ?

```
@After
public void tearDown(){
    //TODO finalize static object A 
}
```

Comment: Quite simply - you can't, without providing some means to reset the `prevId` value. Decreased testability is one of the (many) arguments against mutable static state.

Comment: You can add finalize method to your object which can decrease prevId, but is not mandatory form garbage collector to call it in the end of the test method.

Comment: @ByeBye relying upon finalizer to be executed is a fast road to pain - it shouldn't even be mentioned as an option. If you need something to be executed at a certain time, execute it explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply - you can't, without providing some means to reset the `prevId` value. Decreased testability is one of the (many) arguments against mutable global state.

Instead of relying upon mutable global state like this, you can provide a factory class to create your `A` instances:

```
class AFactory {
  private int nextId;

  A createA() {
    return new A(nextId++);
  }
}
```

You will need to inject a single instance of `AFactory` wherever you currently need to create `A` instances. Now, in your test, you can simply create a new `AFactory` for each test case, and the `nextId` value will be start at zero each time.

---

Alternatively, you could invert control by creating some sort of unique value provider class:

```
final class UniqueValueProvider {
  private int nextId;

  int nextId() {
    return nextId++;
  }
}
```

and then make this a parameter of the constructor of `A`:

```
class A {
  final int id;

  A(UniqueValueProvider uvp) {
    this.id = uvp.nextId();
  }
}
```

which makes it more extensible if you want to arbitrarily subclass `A`:

```
class ChildOfA extends A {
  ChildOfA(UniqueValueProvider uvp) {
    super(uvp);
  }
}
```

Again, in your tests you can simply create a new instance of `UniqueValueProvider`; you'd need to inject a single instance everywhere that you need to create an `A` (or one of its subclasses).

---

As a side note: you can also change the thing that you are testing. Instead of asserting that the ID is 1 each time, you can create two instances, and assert that the IDs are different/1 greater than the other etc:

```
Foo first = new Foo();
Foo second = new Foo();
assertNotEqual(first.getId(), second.getId());
```

Comment: in createA() you use the constructor of A to set the id, 
but I want to avoid to set the Id from outside. should therefore be A a inner class of AFactory ?

Comment: You could, I suppose; or make `AFactory` an inner class of `A`. Or you could make the constructor of `A` package private.

Comment: and how about creating subclasses of A in the factory ? adding further createSubclassB() methods ?

Comment: Added an alternative which might work better for arbitrary subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

If it is really just about the test scenario you described, just use reflection to reset value of the static member variable in your `@Before` method. If you are using Mockito, you can use their `Whitebox` helper to achieve this in a single line like so:

```
import org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.Whitebox;

Foo foo = new Foo();

@Before
public void setup() {
    Whitebox.setInternalState(foo, "STATIC_MEMBER", 0);
}

@Test
public void staticMemberTest() {
     assertEquals(0, foo.next());
     assertEquals(1, foo.next());
 }

@Test
public void anotherStaticMemberTest() {
     assertEquals(0, foo.next());
     assertEquals(1, foo.next());
 }  

private static class Foo {
    private static int STATIC_MEMBER = 0;

    public int next() {
        return STATIC_MEMBER++;
    }
}
```